# GitLab git clone

Tags: gitlab

I have the following problem: I try to clone a project in GitLab using the Git command console (Git CMD) and it gives me an error, because it asks me for the permission of an unknown user. It is worth mentioning that the problem occurs with any project that you want to clone from GitLab. It always presents the same error. I attached the error capture to help me please! Regards.

[image]

Comment: Screenshot says exactly what you should do?

Comment: If you are seeing that message and you are not Pablorincones then you have configured git to use that user.

Also keep in mind: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode